# Formatting a string in binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Using MVVM and Silverlight 5: 
I have defined a property like this, it is not still fully correct but for now it works for my purpose

```
public string DevWannaBe
{
    get
    {
        return "500";
    }
    set
    {
        this._DevWannaBe = "500";
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("_DevWannaBe");
    }
}
private string _DevWannaBe;
```

Now in `XAML` I want to have a line of text that reads as **Found XYZ newbie developers**
Where **XYZ** is variable and coming from value in `DevWannaBe`

I think I should use `StringFormat` as far as I know but how? Something like?

```
Text = "{Binding DevWannaBe, StringFormat = {Found {0} newbie developers}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `Label`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding DevWannaBe}" ContentStringFormat="Found {0} newbie developers"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close:

```
StringFormat='Found \{0\} newbie developers'
```

Works on any element, not just a label.